# How do create a python program that would save strings in csv but all in one block of that row?

Tags: python, csv

[I want this to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBuRs.png)
This is what I want. I have a script that gets the strings portion but whenever I try to append or write it into a CSV file it is not getting on the same block rather the strings are put in different block in a row. [Current script does this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3gXH.png), and I don't want this.

```
final_string = "usafndoas asidnkas ,dioas ais asonxxk asd ascioasopasn xasix xaso asoid"

file = open("protagonist.csv", 'w+')
writer = csv.writer(file)

file.write(str(final_string))
```

How do I do it? It is putting it into separate blocks in a row. But I want it on same block  if possible..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer to understand. Could you show what your desired output file should look like for that input. If you just want to write text to a file, CSV format would not be needed.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for the inconvenience @MartinEvans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`csvwriter.writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) function. This takes a list of items and places each entry into its own cell in the CSV file.

So to write `final_string` as a single value (e.g. A1 in Excel) you can do the following:

```
import csv

final_string = "usafndoas asidnkas ,dioas ais asonxxk asd ascioasopasn xasix xaso asoid"

with open("protagonist.csv", 'w+', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow([final_string])
```

The `[]` has turned `final_string` into a list with a single item.

If you wanted to write other cells (your example shows a `C` in `A1`) you could change this to:

```
csv_output.writerow(["C", final_string])
```

This would create two cells.

Note: Using `with` here has the effect of automatically closing the file for you at the end.

Comment: Thanks so much. This does the work. And thanks again for the explanation note  as well.

Answer (score 0):

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Final project\Requirements2.csv",encoding = 'unicode_escape')`

`print(df)`

Try out this code and give your own .csv file path to this code.